# Hermite interpolation, code in python. Can you guide me on how to solve this exercise

Tags: python-3.x

Can you guide me on how to solve this exercise with python? I need help with this code please

3. Let $f(x)= 3xe^{x}- e^{2x}$

a) Approximate $f(1.03)$ by means of the interpolating Hermite polynomial of degree three using $x_0 = 1\ and \ x_1 = 1.05. $
Compare the actual error with the error bound.
b) Repeat (a) with the Hermite interpolating polynomial of degree five, using $x_0 = 1$, $x_1 = 1.05$ and $x_2 = 1.07. $

¿Pueden orientarme en cómo resolver este ejercicio con python?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please read [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "please help me" is [not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question); we don't write code to specification. [You are expected to study the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ahead of time; think of logical steps to solve the problem; figure out exactly where you are stuck, and be able to show exact input and output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.